# Processingjs Firefox error: "TypeError: $it2.hasNext is not a function"

Tags: javascript, css

I'm getting the above error message in Firefox when loading up [this webpage](http://geotheory.co.uk/). The page runs a processingjs script which runs ok in Chrome and Safari.  I have not used Processing's `smooth()` function, which has given [others](https://processing-js.lighthouseapp.com/projects/41284/tickets/1608-error-in-parsing-value-for-image-rendering-declaration-dropped) this error.

Any idea what this mean?! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Er… is anything actually *broken*? Processing reserves the right to change CSS properties in a compatible way ;)

Comment: Define _broken_ ;) The script fails in Firefox. The processingjs conversion script is the latest v1.4.1, and the script itself is http://geotheory.co.uk/tube7.pde. As for how this is or is not compatible with Firefox's CSS I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, all of those are just CSS warnings — they shouldn’t break any JavaScript. The actual error I get in Firefox is a JavaScript one reading “TypeError: `$it2.hasNext` is not a function.” Are you sure there isn’t more than just the one?

Comment: Thanks minitech, I was looking in the wrong direction. I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in a recent FF release has caused [a bug in Processing](https://processing-js.lighthouseapp.com/projects/41284/tickets/1935-the-for-each-loop-over-arrays-doesnt-work-on-firefox-17).  If you get this problem, [this patch by davidleibovik at GitHub](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/pull/43/files) should get around it.